# Using voltage inverters as voltage boost converters

Tags: electrical-engineering

So recently in one of my circuits I needed to have a -5V power supply, so I used a voltage inverter IC to get -5V from 5V. And the voltage across 5V and -5V is 10V so basically the voltage has been doubled. That got me thinking what would happen if we used another inverter IC but this time -5V would be the ground reference. So if I'm correct this way we would get an output voltage of -15V, and then across -15V and 5v we would have 20V.

I know there are dedicated voltage booster ICs that do this but I noticed they have an efficiency around 80-90% while these voltage inverter ICs are around 99% efficient. Would this be a good way to boost voltages?
Datasheet of inverter: https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/698/REN_icl7660s_a_DST_20121024-1997724.pdf

Comment: "*...  these voltage inverter ICs are around 99% efficent.*" That seems very unlikely. [Edit] to add a datasheet link.

Comment: Did you look at Figure 8 in the datasheet? The efficiency drops dramatically if you try to draw more than a few milliamperes from the inverter.